# Heroku does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rubygems

I have an error on heroku

"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

heroku logs

```
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955259+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955259+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__174253647150912787__process_action__callbacks'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954664+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955547+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.954860+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.955924+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956945+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958307+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.956773+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958055+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2996628356594363701__call__callbacks'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.957615+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958307+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.958307+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-03-26T11:43:11.959400+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=dpm-app.herokuapp.com request_id=8cfcd0b0-fd95-4698-b773-92420b3791fb fwd="159.224.13.90" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=1543
```

my gemfile

```
ruby '2.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.5'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'


# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease.
gem 'jbuilder', '1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20',require: false
end

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

on local server all works.
if you need some more logs, just ask
thanks for your help.

Comment: `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}` - that template exists where it is supposed to be?

Comment: Are you sure you did commit ALL the changes including untracked files?

Comment: i use haml. template on static_pages/home.html.haml

Comment: and local server all works. whats can be wrong?

Comment: yes, i commit all files.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}
```

You need to have a `.html.erb` page at `views/static_pages/home.html.erb`

If your local server works, it could be an issue with precompilation. You should run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` before pushing to Heroku, to see if you're referencing something incorrectly

Comment: I understand that, but I'm using haml. how should I name templates?

Comment: `.html.haml` page at `views/static_pages/home.html.haml`